# How to authenticate user in ONVIF?

Tags: c, authentication, soap, onvif

we have network IP camera that supports ONVIF protocol. When I tried to get its PTZ configuration it gives Auth error. I am implementing this in C. Following are the request and response.

Request:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" 
  "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"" 
  "xmlns:tds=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl\">" 
  "<soap:Body>"
  "<tds:GetNodes/>" 
  "</soap:Body>" 
  "</soap:Envelope>"
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" 
                xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" 
                xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
                xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
                xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
                xmlns:ptzimg2="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" 
                xmlns:ptzimg3="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" 
                xmlns:ptzimg4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2" 
                xmlns:ptzimg5="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2" 
                xmlns:ptzimg6="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1" 
                xmlns:ptzimg1="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl" 
                xmlns:ptzimg7="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/imaging/wsdl" 
                xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error">

<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
        <SOAP-ENV:Code>
            <SOAP-ENV:Value>
                SOAP-ENV:Sender
            </SOAP-ENV:Value>
            <SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
                <SOAP-ENV:Value>
                    ter:NotAuthorized
                </SOAP-ENV:Value>
            </SOAP-ENV:Subcode>
        </SOAP-ENV:Code>
        <SOAP-ENV:Reason>
            <SOAP-ENV:Text xml:lang="en">
                Sender Not Authorized
            </SOAP-ENV:Text>
        </SOAP-ENV:Reason>
        <SOAP-ENV:Node>
            http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/node/ultimateReceiver
        </SOAP-ENV:Node>
        <SOAP-ENV:Role>
            http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/role/ultimateReceiver
        </SOAP-ENV:Role>
        <SOAP-ENV:Detail>
            The action requested requires authorization and the sender is not authorized
        </SOAP-ENV:Detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

How can I authenticate user? Thanks

Comment: Q: Are you hand-coding your SOAP?  Q: What's the camera model and manufacturer?  Do they support an interface library?  Or any specs (besides the WSDL)?  Have you tried contacting them (at least for sample code)?

Comment: Its a Canon camera, VB-M40. This authentication method is given in ONVIF programmer guide. "http://www.onvif.org/Portals/0/documents/WhitePapers/ONVIF_WG-APG-Application_Programmer%27s_Guide.pdf"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

those commands which required authentication. Their authentication headers can be added like this.

```
 snprintf(postData, sizeof(postData),
          "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" 
          "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"" 
          "xmlns:wsse=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401"
          "-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd\""  
          "xmlns:wsu=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-"
          "200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd\""  
          "xmlns:tds=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl\">" 
          "<SOAP-ENV:Header><wsse:Security><wsse:UsernameToken>" 
          "<wsse:Username>%s</wsse:Username>" 
          "<wsse:Password Type=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-"
          "200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest\">"
              "%s</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce>%s</wsse:Nonce>" 
          "<wsu:Created>%s</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken>"
          "</wsse:Security></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body>" 
          "<tds:GetNodes>" 
          "</SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>", 
          username, base64EncDigest, nonce_char, time_char);
```

Comment: How do you generate the password digest? I'm looking through the ONVIF programmers API and it looks like the password digest is produced by performing `Digest = B64ENCODE( SHA1( B64DECODE( Nonce ) + Date + Password ) )` but both date and password are strings that have been converted to binary. What does it mean to convert a string to binary? How did you generate the digest?

Comment: the nonce_char should be base64 encoded? what is time_char? is it timestamp or current time like 2014-01-02T12:47:08Z

Answer (score 2):

You can use gSoap with WSSE plugin to generate C++ client proxy from OnVif WDSL that you require.

Do that greatly simplified my work. Here is an example of calling GetVideoEncoderConfiguration and reading response.

```
_media__GetVideoEncoderConfigurations query;
_media__GetVideoEncoderConfigurationsResponse response;

soap_wsse_add_Security(&mediaProxy);
soap_wsse_add_UsernameTokenDigest(&mediaProxy, NULL, m_username.c_str(), m_password.c_str());

if(mediaProxy.GetVideoEncoderConfigurations(&query, &response) == SOAP_OK)
{
    LogSuccess("GetVideoEncoderConfigurations");
    for(auto it = response.Configurations.begin(); it != response.Configurations.end(); ++it)
    {
        onvif__VideoEncoderConfiguration* videoConf = *it;
        log(I3) << "Name= " << videoConf->Name << ", Encoding=" << videoConf->Encoding << ", Resolution=" << videoConf->Resolution->Width << "x" << videoConf->Resolution->Height;
    }
}
else
    LogError("GetVideoEncoderConfigurations", soap_faultdetail(&mediaProxy));
```

So no manually creating soap messages. gSOAP generated code takes care of that in lower layer. Of course, it takes mi 2 days to generate working code with wsse support, but still it was probably 10 times faster the to do it manualy. If you are interested in further information you can contact me.